# OCB-AES: Ambiguous definition of "Encipher" in RFC document

Tags: aes, block-cipher, terminology, encipher

I'm implementing an OCB-AES cipher (which is described in [RFC 7253](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc7253.pdf)), now I have to call the AES encipher function (I'll refer to that as AES-256, described in [FIPS 197](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/197/final/documents/fips-197.pdf))

**Pre-summary:** I'm not sure which encipher function FIPS 197 refers to. Of course, it should be the cipher function; however, the function parameters are different.

Here's an excerpt from OCB's "associated data hash function":

> ```
>    Function name:
>      HASH
>    Input:
>      K, string of KEYLEN bits                      // Key
>      A, string of any length                       // Associated data
>    Output:
>      Sum, string of 128 bits                       // Hash result
>    Sum is defined as follows.
>      //
>      // Key-dependent variables
>      //
>      L_* = ENCIPHER(K, zeros(128))
>      L_$ = double(L_*)
>      ...
> ```

Another excerpt from OCB:

> ```
> To be complete, the algorithms in this document require ... a blockcipher operating on 128-bit blocks...
>
> ...
>
> ENCIPHER(K,P)  The blockcipher function mapping 128-bit plaintext block P to its corresponding ciphertext block using KEYLEN-bit [256-bit] key K.
> ```

So, I jumped to FIPS 197. Here's the cipher function:

> ```
> Cipher(byte in[4*Nb], byte out[4*Nb], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)])
> begin
>     byte state[4,Nb]
>     state = in
>     AddRoundKey(state, w[0, Nb-1]) 
>     // See Sec. 5.1.4
>     for round = 1 step 1 to Nr–1
>         SubBytes(state) 
>         // See Sec. 5.1.1
>         ShiftRows(state) 
>         // See Sec. 5.1.2
>         MixColumns(state) 
>         // See Sec. 5.1.3
>         AddRoundKey(state, w[round*Nb, (round+1)*Nb-1])
>     end for
>     SubBytes(state)
>     ShiftRows(state)
>     AddRoundKey(state, w[Nr*Nb, (Nr+1)*Nb-1])
>     out = state
> end
> ```

After looking at the table  (where $1 \text{ words} = 4 \text{ bytes}$)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}& \text{Key length }(Nk \text{ words)} & \text{Block size } (Nb \text{ words)} & \text{Number of rounds }(Nr)\\\text{AES }128&4&4&10 \\\text{AES }192&6&4&12\\\text{AES }256&8&4&14\end{array}$$

Paraphrasing only the *input* parameters for $256$:

`void cipher(char in[16], char w[240]);`

**Here's the main point:** The first excerpt wants me to call AES-256 cipher with 1) the key 2) zeros of 16 bytes. **How can I pass the 256-bit key and 128-bit zero?** One parameter has $240$ bytes and the other has $16$? Is my "function prototype" for the cipher wrong, or do I need to use key expansion, etc..., somehow?

Comment: Yes, the 240 bytes are the result of the AES key schedule, which takes a key of length 16, 24 or 32 bytes and returns the appropriate round keys `w`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 256-bit `K` of OCS-AES must first go thru FIPS 197's

> `KeyExpansion(byte key[4*Nk], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)], Nk)`

where it is `key[4*Nk]` to be transformed into `w[Nb*(Nr+1)]` (32×4×(14+1) = 1920-bit), which is the last input of

> `Cipher(byte in[4*Nb], byte out[4*Nb], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)])`